# Detecting the character encoding of an HTTP POST request

Tags: http, rest, http-headers

I'm building a web service and have a node that accepts a POST to create a new resource.  The resource expects one of two content-types - an XML format I'll be defining, or form-encoded variables.

The idea is that consuming applications can POST XML directly and benefit from better validation etc., but there's also an HTML interface that will POST the form-encoded stuff.  Obviously the XML format has a charset declaration, but I can't see how I detect the form's charset just from looking at the POST.

A typical post to the form from Firefox looks like this:

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
Host: www.myhostname.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 [...etc...]
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml, [...etc...]
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 41

field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3
```

Which doesn't seem to contain any useful indication of the character set.

From what I can see, the application/x-www-form-urlencoded type is entirely defined in HTML, which just lays out the %-encoding rules, but doesn't say anything about what charset the data should be in.

Basically, is there any way of telling the character set if I don't know the character set the HTML originally presented was?  Otherwise I'll have to try and guess the character set based on what chars are present, and that's always a bit iffy from what I can tell.

Comment: There are many subtleties here and behavior will vary by browser and operating system. One convention used by IE is that if you have a hidden INPUT with the name `_charset_`, IE will fill in that field with the character set it used when submitting the form. See also related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830546/accept-charset-utf-8-parameter-doesnt-do-anything-when-used-in-form

Answer (score 72, accepted):

the default encoding of a HTTP POST is ISO-8859-1.

else you have to look at the Content-Type header that will then look like

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; charset=UTF-8
```

You can maybe declare your form with

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8">
```

or

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

to force the encoding.

Some references :

http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/form.html

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Comment: well I don't know, I'm not a Web developper, i've added links where you can find some references.

Comment: I tested the default form encoding on Safari and Firefox a few years ago, and found that they always returned UTF-8.  Didn't test on IE.  I should add that the page with the form was in UTF-8.

Comment: I should also add that this appears to be in violation of the HTTP standard (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.4.1 ).  I'm using Tomcat, which claims that the client did not specify a charset in its headers.  (I trust Tomcat, but couldn't verify that it was in fact reading the headers properly.)

Comment: One other thing: HTML4's default format for forms is 'UNKNOWN', i.e. use the page's format.  The issue here is browsers that then refuse to specify the charset in the POST. (See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3 )

Comment: @chburd: This doesn't work on FireFox, by the way. It just ignores the charset from the enctype attribute, and posts in what it wants (UTF-8 it seems).

Comment: @PawelVeselov When you say "ignores it" and uses UTF-8 do you mean that it sends using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` (ok) or that it sends without a `charset` in the Content-Type (which would be evil).

Comment: I deleted the test jsp ;(
To my recollection, it was doing the evil thing.

Comment: @PawelVeselov It seems that chrome does the evil thing :( . Will check a few other browsers later.

Comment: i was trying to produce this bug from last 2 days, your answered saved my time. thanks

Comment: There is actually no way to _enforce_ a specific charset for the server. If the server doesn't understand a given charset (and there are many out there!), it obviously cannot interpret the url-encoded bytestream correctly. I was having trouble with a buggy REST interface (Adobe CQ5) where I actually had to send an two times URL-encoded UTF-8-encoded string while it ignored the provided charset-info. In short: you never know what's happening to your bytes...

Comment: accept-charset="UTF-8" was enough to make it work in a Struts 2 application with commons-fileupload.

Answer (score 10):

The Charset used in the POST will match that of the Charset specified in the HTML hosting the form.  Hence if your form is sent using UTF-8 encoding that is the encoding used for the posted content.  The URL encoding is applied after the values are converted to the set of octets for the character encoding.

Comment: I was more wondering if there was a stateless way of approaching it, as in without knowledge of the form's character set.

Comment: No. The client would have to explicitally declare the charset in the HTTP headers for that to work.

Comment: @CiaranMcNulty that's actually not true, some browsers don't do it. I tried this on FF, forcing the page charset to iso-8859-1, and it still submitted the form in UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the charset on your Content-Type:

```
httpCon.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary=" + boundary );
```

Comment: If you have multiple containers, you pass them with a unique boundary string between them.