# Can we submit euro sign € in html form?

Tags: html, symbols, euro

I'm trying to submit '**€**' (typed on input type=text) but I'm receiving "**â?¬**" instead.

Do we have any solution for this to make me receive correct '**€**' symbol?

Answer (score 1):

in my case i had `<meta charset="utf-8" />` missing

Answer (score 0):

**TRY** : insert `€` inside textbox and submit, it will `echo` symbol

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test" />
<input type="submit" value="go" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['test'];
    exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the HTML name i.e. `&euro;`

See this [link](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for a full list of ASCII codes and HTML equivalents

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a [€](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm) as it is encoded in UTF-8, but you interpret it as a different encoding (possibly [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1)).

Judging by the characters you see (`â?¬`), the byte sequence `0xE2 0x82 0xAC` match ISO-8859-1.

Look at the content-type header of the POST request, as [this answer outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708915/detecting-the-character-encoding-of-an-http-post-request). It will indicate what encoding was used when submitting the form.

**Edit**:
If you get a single `?` when you switch to interpreting the form data as UTF-8, you probably have interpreted it correctly. The reason you do not see a nice `€` could be because you look at the data with an ISO-8859-1 terminal instead of an [ISO-8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) terminal (the former does not have an € sign defined).

Now is a good time to read Joels [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: How do you look at the result? Through a web browser, or in a shell window?

Comment: I debugged the code in my Java file to see what I get (and I got 'â?¬'). I've also made both request and response to have UTF-8 encoding.