# Paypal Rest API only allows alphanumeric names?

Tags: rest, paypal

I'm using Paypal Rest API SDK to "Create a payment". However, when I add Item objects with Chinese characters as "name", it returns server error 400: Must contain only these characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, punctuation(.,#-‘), and embedded spaces). The same constraints apply to shipping address. Is it a limitation of the Rest API? It seems quite a harsh constraint. Must I revert to the classic API in order to use non-alphanumeric strings?

Thanks

Comment: can you somehow define the charset encoding for your request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708915/detecting-the-character-encoding-of-an-http-post-request - It might just be a limitation of the PayPal Rest API for now, better ask the directly (ahd share the answer here for others)

Comment: Can you also update which SDK language (PHP, .NET) are you using so that we can confirm the same too?

Comment: Dear Prasanna_PayPal, I'm using PHP Rest API SDK.