# How to Send Hindi Message in java to an api

Tags: java, character-encoding, hindi

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(SMS_SERVICE_URL);
String dataParameter = getDataParameter(from, toList, text, userName, password);
```

Above is the code for which iam able to send sms message in english using a third party API but iam unable to send sms in regional language like hindi .Any help would be greatly appreciated .

If i send hindi message to the API iam not able to get the SMS also i have logged the message in logger on server getting ????????! ??????? characters in logger files.

Please comment if anything else required for further understanding.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this third party API support sms in Hindi? Is it documented? Did you try contacting their support first? What did they answer?

Comment: You might need to tell the server what character set you're using. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/708942/611819

Comment: They provided me with their console wherein we need to put the user ID password mobile number and the text message to be sent . It's working fine with the console where I need to put Hindi message but getting issue while iam sending sms from code.

Comment: Currenlty iam hardcoding the hindi sentence like String hindiMessage="प्रिय मेंबर, मुबारक हो!"; like this and printing in my log its showing like this ??? ???? ????!

Comment: I have done everthing like changing encoding to UTF-8 its printing fine in console but iam unable to send sms, by the way encoding used at third party is ISO 8859-1 being used for sending hindi SMS